# Дублирование элементов в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

В общем после перезапуска вернуться в Activty, добавляется ещё один список, не пойму из-за чего это происходит, объясните пожалуйста, и расскажите как это исправить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class FragmentMenu extends Fragment implements OnCustomerListChangedListener, OnStartDragListener {

    public static FragmentMenu newInstance() {
        return new FragmentMenu();
    }

    public static ArrayList<ItemMenu> ItemMenuList;
    private AdapterMenu3 adapterMenu3;
    private AdapterMenu4 adapterMenu4;
    private RecyclerView rv_menu;

    private CardView cv_menu_settings, cv_menu_search, cv_switch;

    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static String LIST_OF_SORTED_DATA_ID = "json_list_sorted_data_id";

    private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    public static List<Customer> customers;

    private String LIST_VIEW = "List View";
    private String GRID_VIEW = "Grid View";
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private RecycleViewAdapter recycleViewAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTest(), "История");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTest(), "Избраное");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

        cv_switch = requireView().findViewById(R.id.cv_switch);

        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);

        TabLayout tabLayout = requireView().findViewById(R.id.tl_menu);
        ViewPager viewPager = requireView().findViewById(R.id.vp_menu);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        cv_menu_settings = requireView().findViewById(R.id.cv_menu_settings);
        cv_menu_settings.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivitySettings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            requireActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fragment_fade_enter, R.anim.fragment_fade_exit);
            requireActivity().finish();
        });

        cv_menu_search = requireView().findViewById(R.id.cv_search);
        cv_menu_search.setOnClickListener(v -> drawer_layout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START));

        rv_menu = requireView().findViewById(R.id.rv_menu);

        customers = getSampleData();

        RecyclerView4();

    }
    private void switchView2(String layoutTypeValue) {
        if (layoutTypeValue.equals(LIST_VIEW)){
            gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(SPAN_ONE);
            rv_menu.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        }
        else if (layoutTypeValue.equals(GRID_VIEW)){
            gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(SPAN_THREE);
            rv_menu.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        }
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("LAYOUT_TYPE", layoutTypeValue).apply();
    }

  private void RecyclerView4() {

        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), SPAN_THREE);

        adapterMenu4 = new AdapterMenu4(customers,
                (ClickTasks) getContext(),
                (ClickTraders) getContext(),
                (ClickKeys) getContext(),
                (ClickHandbook) getContext(),
                (ClickLocations) getContext(),
                (ClickRounds) getContext(), gridLayoutManager);

        String CURRENT_VIEW = sharedPreferences.getString("LAYOUT_TYPE", null);
        if (CURRENT_VIEW == null) {
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("LAYOUT_TYPE", LIST_VIEW).apply();
        } else
            switchView2(CURRENT_VIEW);
        cv_switch.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (sharedPreferences.getString("LAYOUT_TYPE", null).equals(LIST_VIEW))
            {
                switchView2(GRID_VIEW);
            } else {
                switchView2(LIST_VIEW);
            }
        });
        rv_menu.setAdapter(adapterMenu4);
    }

    public static List<Customer> getSampleData() {
        List<Customer> customerList = SampleData.addSampleCustomers();
        List<Customer> sortedCustomers = new ArrayList<>();
        String jsonListOfSortedCustomerId = sharedPreferences.getString(LIST_OF_SORTED_DATA_ID, "");

        if (!jsonListOfSortedCustomerId.isEmpty()) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            List<Long> listOfSortedCustomersId = gson.fromJson(jsonListOfSortedCustomerId, new TypeToken<List<Long>>() {
            }.getType());

            if (listOfSortedCustomersId != null && listOfSortedCustomersId.size() > 0) {
                for (Long id : listOfSortedCustomersId) {
                    for (Customer customer : customerList) {
                        if (customer.getId().equals(id)) {
                            sortedCustomers.add(customer);
                            customerList.remove(customer);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (customerList.size() > 0) {
                sortedCustomers.addAll(customerList);
            }

            return sortedCustomers;
        } else {
            return customerList;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас при входе в фрагмент это поле customers заполняется данными:

```
customers = getSampleData();
```

есть три варианта:

1. Очищать массив перед заполнением: `customers.clear();`
2. Присваивать пустой массив при создании фрагмент:

   ```
   List<String> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
   ```
3. [Удалять дубликаты](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist) перед заполнением адаптера данными:

   ```
   Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(yourList);
   yourList.clear();
   yourList.addAll(set);
   ```

Comment: Нужно `customers.clear();` поставить перед `customers = getSampleData();`? В таком случае появляется ошибка `Attempt to invoke interface method 'void java.util.List.clear()' on a null object reference`

Comment: да это логично, потому что данной переменной не присвоено значение, а здесь что происходит - SampleData.addSampleCustomers(); ?